# Slow segue because of passing of data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have two `UIViewController`'s in my app. One of them passes data to the other, before executing a `segue`. However, this segue is really slow and takes a couple of seconds. This is the code:

```
- (IBAction)barButtonRight:(id)sender {
    [[self.restaurant current] setName:self.textField.text];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showRestaurant" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRestaurant"]) {
        UINavigationController *navController = segue.destinationViewController;
        RestaurantViewController *viewController = [navController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        viewController.restaurant = self.restaurant;
    }
}
```

When I comment `viewController.restaurant = self.restaurant` out, the segue is at normal speed. Any thought about how I can solve this?

===

Edit:

Turns out, it's the `UITextView` in the `viewDidLoad` method that's making it slow. This is the code:

```
self.myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
self.myTextView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
self.myTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.myTextView.textColor = [UIColor textColor];
self.myTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Raleway-Light" size:self.myTextView.font.pointSize];
```

Comment: Could you please show what, if anything, the `RestaurantViewController` does when the view appears or is about to appear?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Nothing related to this actually. It just sets up a `UITextView` and sets the text to the restaurant description. There are no extra network calls or anything attached to this.

Comment: I'd try commenting it out anyway, put back `viewController.restaurant = self.restaurant;` into `prepareForSegue`, and see if the timing improves.

Comment: Turns out it's the `UITextView` that's making it load slow. I really don't know why though. I added the code to the question.

Comment: Commenting out the line that sets the font looks the most promising :-)